# How can I send a javascript array to a PHP script using Ajax along with other non-array data?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a site where users can order items. I am currently sending various bits of information to the PHP script so they can be added to the database from there:

```
$.ajax ({
  type: "POST",
  url: "./pay.php",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    "firstName" : firstName,
    "lastName" : lastName,
    "email" : email,
    "price" : price
  }  
});
```

This is working well. Now I would like to send over two arrays that contain the id's and quantities of products that were ordered. Since I don't know how many products there are at any given point or what their id is, I cannot add them as individual items as I have done above. Currently I have the product ID's and their corresponding quantities in separate arrays as such:

```
productIds: ["6", "1"]
quantities: ["1", "4"]
```

I would like to send these arrays to the PHP script along with the rest of the variables so I can loop through those arrays and insert the information into the database.

Can I do that like this?

```
$.ajax ({
      type: "POST",
      url: "./pay.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        "firstName" : firstName,
        "lastName" : lastName,
        "email" : email,
        "price" : price,
        "productIds" : productIds,
        "quantities" : quantities
      }  
 });
```

The non-array variables I am currently able to access like this in the PHP script:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
```

I would like to loop through the productIds array in the PHP script something like this, but I think I am missing something:

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($_POST['productIds'] as $value) {
  $sql = 'INSERT INTO orders SET
  product_id = "'.$_POST['productIds'][$i].'",
  quantity = "'.$_POST['quantities'][$i].'"';

  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  $i++;
}
```

How can I send a javascript array to a PHP script using Ajax along with other non-array data?

Comment: You're just missing the `$` at the beginning of `$i` in the subscripts.

Comment: Did you try just doing `print_r($_POST['productIds'])` to see what's in there?

Comment: Show the output of `var_dump($_POST)`.

Comment: I am trying to print_r or var_dump but the ajax won't work when I try those. I am assuming I receiving an error on the PHP side. I thought those PHP errors would appear in the Console, but I don't see them there? How can I view those errors?

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the arrays to the data parameter

```
var productIds = ["6", "1"];
var quantities = ["1", "4"];
$.ajax ({
  type: "POST",
  url: "./pay.php",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    "firstName" : firstName,
    "lastName" : lastName,
    "email" : email,
    "price" : price,
    "productIds": productIds,
    "quantities": quantities
  }  
});
```

Comment: And then I should be able to access them on the PHP script like I have written in my question?

Comment: @zeckdude Yep, with your `foreach` and `$_POST['productIds'][$i]`

Comment: I am trying to send the arrays as you have shown above, but when I try to print_r the array on the PHP side, I receive an ajax error response. I assume there is a PHP error on the PHP side I cannot see. Any ideas how I can see those?

Comment: @zeckdude Well why are you trying to `print_r` the array? That means it'll be included in the response back to AJAX. Are you sure you want that to be returned to the Javascript?

Comment: @zeckdude remove `dataType: "json",` since your response is not json.

Answer (score 1):

You can form a JavaScript object right when you're collecting the form data. Send that object directly to PHP. Something like so:

```
//Your object could look like this
var data = {
    name: 'blah',
    product_data: {
        '<some product id>': '<some product name>',
        '<another product id>': '<another product name>'
    }
}
```

On the PHP side, you can access the product data as an associative array by the key `product_data` from the $_POST `array`. Now it's up to you how to collect the form data.

**Update:**

```
$products = $_POST['product_data'];
foreach($products as $product_id => $product_name){
    echo $product_id.', '.$product_name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you give me a code example for the PHP side? I am not exactly following.

Answer (score 0):

PHP will accept array parameters, but you must send parameters in its acceptable form,

```
<?php
    $str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";
    parse_str($str);
    echo $first;  // value
    echo $arr[0]; // foo bar
    echo $arr[1]; // baz

    parse_str($str, $output);
    echo $output['first'];  // value
    echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
    echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz
?>
```

For HTTP posts, you can simply visit the array through `$_POST` variable.

On JavaScript side, the code is like this,

```
$.post(url, {'arr[]': array}, function(data){
    // do something with received data
});
```

Comment: This looks interesting but I cannot see how to implement this on the javascript side. Can you help me out with that?