# how to send this array via ajax to php file?

Tags: php, ajax

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to send arrays like this? php always getting null `$_POST`

Comment: Please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994950/how-can-i-send-a-javascript-array-to-a-php-script-using-ajax-along-with-other-no

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I send a javascript array to a PHP script using Ajax along with other non-array data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994950/how-can-i-send-a-javascript-array-to-a-php-script-using-ajax-along-with-other-no)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, you didn't provide enough information. This is a simple example where i'm sending **user** and **email**. I hope this can help you.

**AJAX**:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "post_route",
    data: {user:'xyz', email:'test@gmail.com'},
    success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    }
});
```

**Route:**

```
Route::post('/post_route', 'TestController@post');
```

**Controller:**

```
public function post(Request $request){

    if($request->ajax()) {
    //return dd($request);
        $user = $request->get( "user" );
        $email = $request->get( "email" );
    }
```

Comment: I'd want to send my whole array i prepared(console log image) VIA Ajax data. While im trying to send my array, PHP $_post is just empty